# How to use SQL Update in N-Tier Data Application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

I get some information and idea in this tutorial [(click here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx) to create my first N-Tier data application with asp.net, But the problem is when I tried to use update query in my `DataAccessTier` I get 1 error in `DataService`.

**Error:**

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable'    C:\Users\BA-OJT\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GoActiveDirectory\DataService\Service1.cs 59  20  DataService
```

How can I fix this?

**My Source-code:**

**Project:** DataAccessTier **Query:** UpdateBySAN

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ActiveDirectory2] 
SET [SamAccountName] = @SamAccountName, [Surname] = @Surname, [GivenName] = @GivenName, [EmailAddress] = @EmailAddress, [Enabled] = @Enabled, [Guid] = @Guid, [DateCreated] = @DateCreated, [DateModified] = @DateModified, [SID] = @SID, [EmployeeNumber] = @EmployeeNumber 
WHERE (SamAccountName = @SamAccountName);

SELECT ID, SamAccountName, Surname, GivenName, EmailAddress, Enabled, Guid, DateCreated, DateModified, SID, EmployeeNumber FROM ActiveDirectory2 
WHERE (SamAccountName = @SamAccountName)
```

**Project:** DataService **Class:** IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable UpdateAccountBySAN(
        string SamAccountName, string Surname, string GivenName, string EmailAddress,
        bool Enabled, string Guid, string DateCreated, string DateModifide, string SID,
        string EmployeeNumber);
```

**Project:** DataService **Class:** Service1.cs

```
public DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable UpdateAccountBySAN(
        string SamAccountName, string Surname, string GivenName, string EmailAddress,
        bool Enabled, string Guid, string DateCreated, string DateModified, string SID,
        string EmployeeNumber)
    {
        DataAccessTier.GW_UTADataSetTableAdapters.ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter
            ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1
                = new DataAccessTier.GW_UTADataSetTableAdapters.ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter();

        return ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1.UpdateBySAN(
            SamAccountName, Surname, GivenName, EmailAddress, Enabled, Guid, DateCreated,
            DateModified, SID, EmployeeNumber); //ErrorRedLine@ ActiveDirectorr2TableAdapter1.UpdateBysan() Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable'
    }
```

Comment: what is the return type of ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1.UpdateBySAN?

Comment: @lboshuizen The query inside `.UpdateBySAN` is the `DataAccessTier` It will going to update and return the updated data.

Comment: What it should do is another thing :-). What is the type that  ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1.UpdateBySAN currently and just in your code returns?

Comment: By default update statement returns how many rows updated. That value is of type integer and its unable to convert as DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable.

Comment: Think... If statement returns the amount of rows updated, is that the same as the whole DataEntityTier.GW_UTADataSet.ActiveDirectory2DataTable?

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota Please read the query I use SELECT NOT RETURN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some experiments I found how to solve my own problem.

For those who following this tutorial [(click here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx) and want to use Update Query in `DataAccessTier`

To use update you can use `int` rather than `ActiveDirectory2DataTable`, Because `ActiveDirectory2DataTable` is only use to receive the table from `DataAccessTier` and the update query will only return the count of updated rows.

---

**Project** DataAccessTier **Name:** UpdateAccountBySAN(@parameterhere...)

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ActiveDirectory2] SET [SamAccountName] = @SamAccountName, [Surname] = @Surname, [GivenName] = @GivenName, [EmailAddress] = @EmailAddress, [Enabled] = @Enabled, [Guid] = @Guid, [DateCreated] = @DateCreated, [DateModified] = @DateModified, [SID] = @SID, [EmployeeNumber] = @EmployeeNumber WHERE (SamAccountName = @SamAccountName);
SELECT ID, SamAccountName, Surname, GivenName, EmailAddress, Enabled, Guid, DateCreated, DateModified, SID, EmployeeNumber FROM ActiveDirectory2 WHERE SamAccountName = @SamAccountName
```

**Project:** DataService **Class:** IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    int UpdateAccountBySAN( string SamAccountName, string Surname, string GivenName,string EmailAddress,bool Enabled, string Guid, string DateCreated, string DateModified,string SID, string EmployeeNumber);
```

**Project:** DataService **Class:** Service1.cs

```
public int UpdateAccountBySAN(string SamAccountName, string Surname, string GivenName, string EmailAddress,bool Enabled, string Guid, string DateCreated, string DateModified, string SID,string EmployeeNumber)
    {
        DataAccessTier.GW_UTADataSetTableAdapters.ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter
            ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1
                = new DataAccessTier.GW_UTADataSetTableAdapters.ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter();
        return ActiveDirectory2TableAdapter1.UpdateBySAN(SamAccountName, Surname, GivenName,
        EmailAddress, Enabled, Guid, DateCreated, DateModified, SID, EmployeeNumber);
    }
```

and to use this in PresentationTier.

**PresentationTier**

```
DataServiceReference.Service1Client newService = new DataServiceReference.Service1Client();

newService.UpdateAccountBySAN(_SamAccountName,_Surename,_GivenName,_EmailAddress,_Enable,_Guid,_DateCreated,_DateModified,_SID,_EmployeeNumber);
//To know how many rows updated use: var _UpdatedRows = newService.UpdateAccountBySAN(<!--some parameter here-->);
```

This is my answer to my problem, I hope this give some to idea future proponents. thank you.